# Selecting rows where a numeric column value change sign through openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I'm learning Python and openpyxl for data analysis on a large xlsx workbook. I have a `for` loop that can iterate down an entire column. Here's some example data:

```
ROW:  VALUE:
1      1
2      2
3      3
4      4
5     -4
6     -1
7     -6
8      2
9      3
10    -3
```

I want to print out the row in which the value changes from positive to negative, and vice versa. So in the above example, row number 5, 8, and 10 would print in the console. How can I use an `if` statement within a `for` loop to iterate through a column on openpyxl?

So far I can print all of the cells in a column:

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('ngt_log.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sheet1')
for i in range(1, 10508, 1):   # 10508 is the length of the column
    print(i, sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value)
```

My idea was to just add an `if` statement inside of the `for` loop:

```
for i in range(1, 10508, 1):   # 10508 is the length of the column
    if(( i > 0 and (i+1) < 0) or (i < 0 and (i+1) > 0)):
        print((i+1), sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value)
```

But that doesn't work. Am I formulating the `if` statement correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me as though your statement is contradicting itself

```
for i in range(1, 10508, 1):   # 10508 is the length of the column
if(( i greater than 0 and (i+1) less than 0) or (i less than 0 and (i+1) greater than 
0)):
    print((i+1), sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value)
```

I wrote the > and < symbols in plain English but if i is greater than 0 then i + 1 is never less than 0 and vise versa so they will never work as both cannot be true

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the sheet.cell values first, and *then* do the comparisons:

```py
end_range = 10508
for i in range(1, end_range):
    current, next = sheet.cell(row=i, column=6).value, sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=6).value
    if current > 0 and next < 0 or current < 0 and next > 0:
        print(i+1, next)
```

I am pretty sure there's a sign() function in the math library, but kinda overkill. You may also want to figure out what you want to do if the values are 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the rules to select the rows where the sign has changed and put them in a generator expression without using extra memory, like this:

```
pos = lambda x: x>=0
keep = lambda s, c, i, v: pos(s[c][x].value)!=pos(v.value)
gen = (x+1 for x, y in enumerate(sheet['f']) if x>0 and keep(sheet, 'f', x-1, y))
```

Then, when you need to know the rows where the sign has changed, you just iterate on `gen` as below:

```
for row in gen:
   # here you use row
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag to check for positive and negative.

```
ws = wb['sheet1'] # why people persist in using long deprecated syntax is beyond me
flag = None

for row in ws.iter_rows(max_row=10508, min_col=6, max_col=6):
    cell = row[0]
    sign = cell.value > 0 and "positive" or "negative"
    if flag is not None and sign != flag:
        print(cell.row)
flag = sign
```